# Andoid recyclerview - What happens when a diffutil areContentsTheSame returns wrong result

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-diffutils

I'm looking into some Janky stats for a RecyclerView.  What would happen if you responded that the contents of some items were the same when they weren't?  Would it cause a lot of bad redrawing?

Comment: If diff says items are the same then they are not updated and will keep displaying whatever was bound to them. Keep in mind that diff is mostly relevant for items that are already laid out on the screen, while scrolling "new" items are bound to current data.